# Determining when Listbox has finished loading bound elements

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, binding

I have a ListBox bound to a collection of objects, and everything works except I don't know how to call some code I need executed when an item in the list is selected.

To be clear, I have already hooked up the  `Listbox_SelectionChanged` event for when the user *selects a different* item - and that works fine.

When the ListBox *is first shown*, though, I want to call that same code on the first item in the list, which it defaults to. Something like `ListBox_BoundDataFinishLoading`, or something..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook to the ItemList-Changed event and select the first item after it is added:

```
public MyWindow()  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  

    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)ListBox.Items).CollectionChanged +=  
        ListBox_CollectionChanged;  
}  

private void ListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender,   
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && ListBox.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        ListBox.SelectedItem = e.NewItems[0];
    }      
}
```

Comment: The only NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs action I get is a Reset

Comment: That should also do the job, because Reset means the list is changed dramatically (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx), e.g. reloaded, so just select the first item after the Reset...

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure if you really can find secure notification of WPF databinding finished. But may be you can do the following:

You said that you already handle SelectionChanged notification from control, so this is UI -> DataModel workflow. If in your binded object you have Selected property and bind it to control (to let's say highlight the row), that means that on SelectionChanged event you can do Selected=true, which will do UI-> ViewModel-> UI (to select a row). but this also means that at moment of initial binding of your ViewModel objects collection SHOULD be enough to you to set Selected property of the first element to true.

To me it's difficult to say if it will really work in your case, as I don't know your app's architecture, but this can be one of the ways to follow.

Hope this helps.

Regards.